# How to get the indexes of the clicked JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a matrix of `JButton[][]`. I try to add `ActionListener` to the buttons which stores the index of the button.

I need to make a game.

The first click shows from which button should I step and the second shows where to step.

Comment: did you understand the answer?

Comment: Do you have knowledge with inheritance??

Comment: *"I try to add ActionListener to the buttons which stores the index of the button."* I try to add ActionListener to the buttons which stores the index of the button. In this case, you might ask for the component corresponding to the event `ActionEvent.getSource()` then iterate the button array until that component equals the current indices.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need can be achieved in several ways, using HashMaps, 2D Arrays, etc etc... here is my suggestion:

**Inheritance**: you need now a Button with 2 properties that are not defined by default (col and row)

```
class MatrixButton extends JButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8557137756382038055L;
    private final int row;
    private final int col;

    public MatrixButton(String t, int col, int row) {
    super(t);
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow() {
    return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
    return col;
    }
}
```

---

you have for sure a Panel where you can add JButtons, now add instead a **MatrixButton**

```
 panel.add(MatrixButton);
```

then add the actionlistener

```
button1.addActionListener(this);
```

and when you click you get the position coordinates by doing

```
   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == this.button1) {
        System.out
            .println(((MatrixButton) ae.getSource()).getRow() + "," + ((MatrixButton) ae.getSource()).getCol());
    } else if (ae.getSource() == this.button2) {
        // TODO
    } else if (ae.getSource() == this.button3) {
        // TODO
    }
    }
```

Comment: `get` / `putClientProperty` :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I try to add ActionListener to the buttons which stores the index of the button.

In this case, you might simply get for the object of the event `ActionEvent.getSource()` then iterate the button array until that object equals the current indices. See the `findButton(Object)` method for implementation.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ButtonArrayIndices {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private JButton[][] buttonArray = new JButton[10][5];
    JLabel output = new JLabel("Click a button");

    ButtonArrayIndices() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void findButton(Object c) {
        for (int x = 0; x < buttonArray.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < buttonArray[0].length; y++) {
                if (c.equals(buttonArray[x][y])) {
                    output.setText(x + "," + y + " clicked");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                findButton(e.getSource());
            }
        };

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 10, 2, 2));
        ui.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(bi);
        Insets margin = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        for (int y = 0; y < buttonArray[0].length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < buttonArray.length; x++) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                buttonArray[x][y] = b;
                b.setMargin(margin);
                b.setIcon(ii);
                b.addActionListener(buttonListener);
                buttonPanel.add(b);
            }
        }

        output.setFont(output.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
        ui.add(output, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                ButtonArrayIndices o = new ButtonArrayIndices();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, looks like as for me the class `findButton` == `get` / `putClientProperty` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button's text to be the relevant index:

```
//while creating the buttons
for(int i = 0; i<buttons.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<buttons[i].length;j++){    
        //create the button
        buttons[i][j] = new JButton((""+i*buttons.length+j));
    }
}
```

and then you can check what the button's index is:

```
//for the first click
try{
    int from = Integer.parseInt(button.getText());// get the button index as int from the text
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

very similarly for the second click.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your class that accepts an index

```
public void handleClick(int r, int c) { ... }
```

when you create your buttons add an action listener which calls this method with the correct indices:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

buttons = new JButton[rowSize][colSize];
IntStream.range(0, rowSize).forEach(r -> {
    IntStream.range(0, colSize).forEach(c -> {
        buttons[r][c] = new JButton(String.format("%d, %d", r, c));
        buttons[r][c].addActionListener(e -> handleClick(r, c));
    });
});
```

Comment: then just to add `get` / `putClientProperty` :-) inside forEach